# how to assign to list of string type of the response from a service field of type list of string

Tags: c#, list, web-services, object, c#-4.0

I am just curious if I need to create an object of Type first? Type is of type `List<string>`

```
public List<string> Types { get ; set ;}
```

I am curious if I have to do `Types = new List<string>();` and then assign to it? in the code below.

```
Response response = null;

if (serviceResponse!= null)
{
    response = new Response 
    {
        Message = serviceResponse.Message,
        Types = serviceResponse.Types
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand your question. Can you clarify it?

Comment: @Pretasoc: I have updated my question

Comment: In that case you don't need to create an instance.

Comment: @Pretasoc: Thank you so much. Why only for objects I have seen people creating else it throws null ref exception?

Comment: I assumed `serviceResponse.Types` is not null. If that is not guaranteed and you want the `Types` property of the `Response` object to be non null my previous commen is wrong.

Comment: @Learner: *"Why only for objects I have seen people creating else it throws null ref exception?"* - That sounds like a different question then what you're asking above, and one which would have its own example code to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to create an instance if you plan to use that instance.  For example:

```
Response response = new Response();
response.Types.Add(someObject);
```

In the above code, if constructing the `Response` object doesn't initialize the `Types` field then a `NullReferenceException` would be thrown.  In the code you have, however, you don't *use* the field but instead *assign* to the field:

```
Response response = new Response 
{
    Message = serviceResponse.Message,
    Types = serviceResponse.Types
};
```

If you initialize the `Types` field in object creation, that instance would almost immediately be thrown away and replaced with the instance you assigned to it.

So, no, in the example you provide you technically do not need to initialize the property.  **However**, keep in mind that by not initializing the property the class holds the assumption that consuming code *will* initialize it.  In this one example that assumption is upheld.  But what about future examples?  Will that assumption always be upheld in the future?  Can you guarantee that?

In general it's a *good idea* to initialize collection properties.  It's not *required*, and not doing so *does* incur an extremely small performance improvement because you're not instantiating an object just to immediately throw it away and replace it.  But the risk is that your consuming code must *always* remember to perform this initialization.

Comment: Thank you but I am layman I am afraid I dont understand. I especially didn't understood what is mean by "if constructing the Response object doesn't initialize the Types". Absolutely that is a class, and I don't have anything in that class but just these two properties. No constructors to initialise that properties or even List<string>

Comment: I have seen people creating object before initialising say List<Products> product = new List<products>(); product.Types = new Types(); product.Types.Name = Name; Now my question is, why the heck we need to create object for this "Types" here and why not for list<string>

Comment: @Learner: I'm afraid that example doesn't make much sense.  Why would `List<products>` have a property called `Types`?  It sounds like you may have some other example code, or perhaps can create some, which produces an unexpected error.  Your question doesn't include any of this.  If what you're asking is masking another *different* question, please clarify.  We only know the question you ask, not the question you're thinking of while you ask something else.

Comment: my question here is irrelevant of code in the question. My point again, is, I have seen people creating objects of custom types and why not for list<string> is my SIMPLE question that I am breaking head to understand

Comment: @Learner: Well, a List<> is an object like any other.  In order to use an object, any object, you must initialize it somewhere.  Maybe in some cases an already initialized object is returned from a method, or created in the internal workings of a framework, or something else.  But somewhere it has to be initialized.

Comment: David, Again, and finally, I am telling you I didn't implement list<string> in microsoft C#. I am (In my visibility), using it thats all. I just need a layman answer, I am a project manager and business analyst doing coding. Now I understand list<string> initialized in .net framework by microsoft? Is thta what you mean?

Comment: @Learner: *Again*, and *finally*, “implement” and “initialize” are two very different things.  The .NET Framework has implemented a class called List<>.  In order to use an instance of that class, you must initialize an instance of that class.  Think of it like a blueprint for a house.  Microsoft wrote the blueprint (implemented) for that class.  But you can’t live in a blueprint.  In order to live in the house, you must construct (initialize) the house.  You can construct as many as you like, anywhere you like.  But in order to use one you must construct (initialize) one.

Comment: David. Trust me I am very well extremely confused now, I don't understand any and all concepts I had known earlier also I got lost reading these. I am absolutely not taking on you, you are after all helping me. But it's not the way I could digest. Anyway I don't get errors lol, so happy as long as I have the code working. I will also give you a thumbs up for your answer and accept it ;)